LNK2019 error compiling C program from a commandline
I was researching a problem and ran across this question:
Convert SetPixel coordinates to pixels on console
Here is the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{

    HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(myconsole, &rect);
    for(int i = 0; i < rect.bottom - rect.top; ++i)
        SetPixel(mydc, (rect.right - rect.left) / 2, i, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    for(int i = 0; i < rect.right - rect.left; ++i)
        SetPixel(mydc, i, (rect.bottom - rect.top) / 2, RGB(255, 0, 0));
}

It compiles and runs in Visual Studio, but from a commandline (cl test.c) I get the following errors:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetPixel@16 referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetDC@4 referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetClientRect@8 referenced in function _main
[cl] 


See SetPixel function you need to link against Gdi32.lib or Gdi32.dll. (e.g. you can just add gdi32.lib at the end of your command line)

If you look up the functions you're missing like SetPixel you can scroll down and see which library you need to link with. You could also add #pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib") to your code to pull the library in.

Does this answer your question? What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?

I posted an answer about this define #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502 before including windows.h -- which handled the situation for me.  On closer inspection of your issue and more thought, I think Retired Ninja gave the solution here in comments, and my situation was different.  Anyway, thanks for sharing this code.  I've never seen graphics painted in a console window before and now I'm hooked, lol.  (The red crosshairs over lightgreen text on black background is just sweet! :-)  )

If you compile from command line then you have to add at least Gdi32.lib and Kernel32.lib (probably User32.lib) libraries.

kernel32.lib is not needed, simply adding gdi32.lib user32.lib at the end of the command line, or using two #pragma directives to do the same thing is all that is needed. (though depending on the terminal the colors and draw and immediately erased on program exit) If you want to add sleep(), then you will need kernel32.lib.
